# How to make a php function working inside an echo?

Tags: php, echo

I tried adding HTML inside a PHP echo, and it works.

But the echo is not working if with a PHP function,

The original code:

```
if( ! function_exists("rframework_cart_button") ){
    function rtframework_cart_button(){

        $show_cart = get_theme_mod( RT_THEMESLUG.'_top_shortcut_buttons_cart' ) ? true : false ;

        if( ! class_exists('Woocommerce') || ! $show_cart ){
            return;
        }

        global $woocommerce;

        echo '<li class="cart"><a href="#" class="cart-menu-button"><span class="icon-shopping-bag"><sub class="number empty">'. $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count .'</sub></span></a></li>'."\n";

    }
}
```

The PHP code I want to put inside or after the echo is:

```
<?php $wishlist_count = YITH_WCWL()->count_products(); ?><span class=”your-counter-selector“><?php echo $wishlist_count; ?></span>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe your question is not clear but can you not add another `echo` after the first with your HTML string or even after your function call, eg `rtframework_cart_button(); echo '<li...';`

Comment: YES, I also tried another echo under the echo, it works if is HTML, but not working if with PHP function, that's why I need help.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53219940/edit) and explain what you mean with examples.

Comment: @bard see my updated answer. your initial question was unclear

Comment: I am a frontend designer, could not know how to edit my question more clear because I don't understand PHP, that's why I am here.

Comment: I am sorry that I had a wrong code in the original post, I had it edited.

Answer (score 2):

with echo, you need to change all the double quotes inside the html stuff to single quotes and keep double quotes outside.
Try this:

```
  return "<li class='cart'><a href='#' class='cart-menu-button'><span class='icon-shopping-bag'><sub class='number empty'>{ $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count }</sub></span></a></li>'.'\n";
```

your question was quite confusing but I got an update based on your comment.

echo within a function called from another function will just output the echo to your page before the end of the other function, using return instead of echo will place that code snippet to the other function. it is the preferred way.

If in html, `<?php functionWithEcho() ?>` or  `<?php echo functionWithReturn()`

if in php, call function normally

Comment: I tried put your code after the echo, but not working, the page keeps loading.

Comment: @bard don't put it after the echo, change the echo to return

Comment: still not working if I replace the echo line to your return, or I have a misunderstanding?

Comment: @bard probably a misunderstanding, I wouldn't know unless I see both functions, perhaps you can update your answer with both?

From what I understand, you echo is working when you call it from html but not from another php function. update question with both and I can help better.

Comment: Well, I check again your code, I guess you didn't know what I wanted to add, not replacing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<li class='cart'><a href='#' class='cart-menu-button'><span class='icon-shopping-bag'><sub class='number empty'>'". $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ."'</sub></span></a></li>.'\n'";
echo "<li class='heart'><a href='#' class='heart-button'><span class='icon-new-heart-1'><sub class='number empty'>0</sub></span></a></li>";
```